# SegFault while trying to use non-null pointer to QGridLayout (Qt)

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying to write a layout manager that is capable of showing all added widgets, filtering them or resizing some of them. I have a QWidget subclass that has currentList of widgets, list of all widgets, prevList of widgets that are shown before last change.
It also has a currentGrid(QGridLayout*) that shows the widgets accordingly and mainLayout that holds the grid and some buttons.

If a change occurs I call updateLayout function whose summary is as follows:
   - Fill prevList from currentGrid
   - Clear and delete mainLayout
   - Clear currentGrid
   - Fill currentGrid from currentList
   - create new mainLayout
   - addButtons
   - add currentGrid

When I add just 1 widget it works very well. When I tried to add second it gives a segfault.

Here is how I clear the mainLayout

```
if(mainLayout) //clear mainLayout
{
    while(mainLayout->count() > 0)
        mainLayout->takeAt(0);
    delete mainLayout;
}
```

Here is the next line of this code and where segfault occurs is showed by (-->).

```
if(currentGrid)
{
    -->while(currentGrid->count() > 0)
    {
        currentGrid->takeAt(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't delete QObjects with delete. Use deleteLater().

Comment: Can you tell me what is the difference?

Comment: Qt-docs: **The object will be deleted when control returns to the event loop.** QObjects can have a 'secret' life. Be it due to signals/slots, be it due to events. For instance, in your case, you remove an item from your layout, the layout content gets rearranged. An event might get posted, so other parts of the gui might act accordingly... but suddently the sender is deleted. deleteLater() makes sure that the object is deleted, when it is safe to do so.

Answer (score 0):

I bet `currentGrid` has been deleted.

Anyway, `delete mainLayout;` doesn't like me. Add `mainLayout = 0;` after it...

Comment: - Fill prevList from currentGrid <--- here it works thus not deleted  
  

- Clear and delete mainLayout <--- I use takeAt function which returns the item thus don't delete, when I delete the layout it's empty  

- Clear currentGrid <--- thus here it's not deleted  

or I'm really in a totally wrong way

Comment: of course, it's impossible to know without the *full* code involved. But - trust me - SIGSEGV means you deleted the *pointed* object...

Answer (score 0):

Your code is incomplete, but it doesn't make much sense to continuously delete and recreate the layouts.

Your "clearing" of the layout is incorrect. You want:

```
void clearLayout(QLayout * layout) {
    while (layout->count() > 0) delete layout->takeAt(0);
}
```